# Objective-C/ARC ivar vs property

Tags: objective-c

I've been up and down the Google and the Stack and read many articles if not outright debates over ivars and properties.  But still, even after all this reading I remain confused.

I understand ivar's are private and properties are typically used to expose (well) class properties.  But I understand properties to be more than that, they contain Getters and Setters and when it comes to memory management (even under ARC) I can see the benefit to using them exclusively.

But my question is; does any of this matter anymore now that we have ARC?  (see comment in example code below).

Consider:

```
@interface MyClass
@property(strong) NSMutableArray *myArray;
@end

@interface MyClass

-(instancetype)init {

    if (self = [super init]) {

        self.myArray = [NSMutableArray array];

        // OR

        // Will this NOT call the Setter?  Hence, leading
        // to possible memory leak issues?
        _myArray = [NSMutableArray array];

    }

    return self;
}
@end
```

Comment: Basic difference: properties have automatic getters and setters, ivars do not.

Comment: yes, ARC works at the property level--release/retain are called when a strong location (not just property) is assigned to.

Comment: `_myArray = value` will not call the setter, but it will retain the assigned value.

Comment: will retain the value, but will not release the previous (because the setter wasn't called) -- am I getting that right?

Comment: yes, the previously stored value will be sent a *release* message. When you assign a value to a strong variable, the value currently in the variable is released.

Comment: That does not, however, necessarily happen if the property is declared to be `weak`.

Comment: @nielsbot I know, I am just clarifying for anyone who is reading who might not know.

Comment: Also, whether the object is actually sent a *release* message could be considered an implementation detail. Just think of it as a strong reference to the object being deleted (somehow).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In both cases the assigned value will be retained, since you are assigning it to a strong variable. (Strong is the default for variables that reference object instances)

In the first example the method *-setMyArray:* will be called, which in the case of a generated setter will store the value to _myArray. In the second case, *-setMyArray:* will not be called.

For the given code the object already assigned to _myArray will have its reference count properly decremented when the _myArray is set again. (The existing strong reference to the object will be deleted.)

Answer (score 1):

`self.myArray = [NSMutableArray array];` is considered bad form in `init`. You should avoid the use of setters entirely in your initialisation. The risk is that a subclass may override the method, in which case you're calling a method on a class that hasn't been `init`ed yet (because it's got only as far as `init`ing you). See the [obligatory Mike Ash citation](https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2009-11-27-using-accessors-in-init-and-dealloc.html).

`_myArray = ...` does not call the setter and is therefore the correct form for an `init` regardless of whether you also have a property.

ARC makes correct memory-management all but a none issue. The debate is exclusively what you want technically to expose and how adaptable you want your internal code to be. I tend to prefer explicit instance variables because that shouts 'private implementation detail'.

Answer (score 1):

Back in the old days of Objective-C, you had ivars, and if you wanted to let some other class set or read them then you had to define a getter and a setter.

As I explained to you, with properties you get the setter and getter for free (almost!) along with an instance variable. So when you define a property, you can set the atomicity as well as assign/retain/copy memory management semantics.

Most people leave the ivar name the same as the property name, but it can be made to be something else when you write your @synthesize statement (i.e., @synthesize foo=_foo; means make an ivar named _foo for the property foo).

Note that as of Xcode 4.6, you do not need to use the @synthesize statement - by default will the compiler prepend the ivar's name with _. So @synthesize is no longer recommended by Apple for new code.

Answer (score 0):

That first call will call the setter while the second will not, however both calls will overwrite the ivar `_myArray`. For example, if you did `self.myArray = @[@"Hello"];` and then `_myArray = @[@"World"]`, printing out both `self.myArray` or `_myArray` will print `@[@"World"]`.

If you instead write your own method `-(void)setMyArray;`, It could possibly do different things, but then you also won't get the private ivar `_myArray` without declaring it yourself.

Comment: Ok, so this confirms to my understanding.  Typically when I code and I see to SET a value, I use property and when I read a value I use the ivar variable.

Comment: It's recommended to use the property methods for both setting and getting unless you have a good reason not to. One of the reasons for this is if you ever want to use KVO to observe changes or simply do anything extra while setting or getting a variable, you can easily add that functionality later. Of course, inside the setter and getter, you'll want to use the ivar so you don't run into an infinite loop.